# Can we use same ssh key for two different accounts

Tags: git, github

If my computer have only one ssh key then can we use the same key for two github accounts

Comment: Off-topic here. If your PC is running Linux or Unix, ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this is because the auth system currently cannot handle multiple users with the same SSH keys. The only way this can be improved would be to make it so that if multiple users have the same SSH key, when you auth with that key, you get the permissions of all users with that key. However, this is not a good idea. Why? Because you shouldn't be sharing keys between machines, nor between roles. Sharing keys between machines increases the probability that the key will get compromised (if you do it right, this probability is still low, but it still increases for each machine you put the same key on). Once a shared key is compromised, not only do you have to kill it on every service you use it for, but you also have to go to every machine to update to the new key. Sharing keys across roles is bad for the same reason, but is actually worse, because once it's compromised, the attacker has a lot more permissions than they would have.
Taking this a step further, you should have 1 key per machine, per role, per service. Sure, this sounds like a lot of keys to manage, but it really isn't. You can easily run multiple ssh-agents (your keys are encrypted on disk, right?), and just change SSH_AUTH_SOCK in your environment to point to the right agent as needed. You can even name the sockets something handy using ssh-agent -a /path/to/socket, allowing you to name sockets by role and service on your machine. If a key is compromised (single key compromise is more likely than all the keys on a machine being compromised.
So, No - you'll need a separate key for each account. Although you need multiple ssh key pairs for multiple accounts you can configure multiple ssh identities and use via aliases on your machine. You can also just use your username in place of "git" or "hg". Still need separate keys, though. Regarding pushing to team repositories, you can do so under your individual account provided you have write or admin access to the repository under the team, in the same way you would with repositories under an individual's account. The team account as a Github/Bitbucket login no longer works.

But in practice you often do not get the chance to know when, which, where or how a key has been compromized, so if I were to suspect it happened to one of my keys, I would change them all and on every single service I use them for, just in case. Imho the best protection is to make a habit of regularly changing your keys, the higher the frequency, the better the security. In such a scheme, I think it's secure enough to have a single SSH key per machine, and I think you could imagine the pain in the ass it would be to change all of my keys once per month if I had one per machine, role and service as you suggest.
I think it's only a matter of taste after all, and both security schemes are valid enough not to arbitrarily decide to favour one and prevent the other, especially on a platform as Github.

The only I've found around this is to clone via http for the personal repos, and clone via ssh for the company repos.

I just use more than one key, one for work, and one for personal. I use Putty Ageant, so I don't have to log in all the time. Then in hgrc, under [ui] add an alias for ssh, and add a command line option to specify which key to use for that repository:

```
[ui]
ssh = TortoisePlink.exe -ssh -2 -batch -C -i H:\Users\myname\.ssh\my_company_private_key.ppk
```

It is kind of annoying to have to change the hgrc after cloning, but workable. But I have since decided to just merge my personal and work. All my work code goes under a team, so not a big deal, and my personal stuff just remains under my name.